# findAndModify, How to make operations on document's array search objects and change fields values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I try to find one object in document's array, and update its fields.

```
db.rescuemodels.findAndModify({
    query: {
        "features": {
            $elemMatch: {
                "properties.title": "W"
            }
        }
    },
    update: {
        $set: {
            "features": {
                "properties": {
                    "title": "XXX"
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Query is fine, result is one matching element, but how to make update method change just one field in this example `title`? Because now it create new array or object and clean old array.

Comment: Have you tried $set: {"features.properties.title": "XXX"}

Comment: I'm amazed that everyone else viewing this missed that this was about updating an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB has ["Dot Notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) for this purpose, as well as the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator for referencing matched elements of an array:

```
  db.rescuemodels.findAndModify({
      "query": { "features.properties.title":"W" }, 
      "update": { "$set": { "features.$.properties.title":"XXX" } }
  })
```

Note that this only works when there is a single array present as in:

```
{
    "features": [
        { "properties": { "name": "A" } },
        { "properties": { "name": "W" } }
    }
}
```

If you are nesting arrays then MongoDB cannot match in "positional operator beyond the "outer" array only:

```
{
    "features": [
       { "properties": [{ "name": "A" }, { "name": "W" }] },

    ]
}
```

Postional matching will not work there because you cannot do `features.$.properties.$.name` and the matched element index would be `0` and not `1` as this refers to the outer array.

Also note that under nodejs the MongoDB driver syntax for [`.findAndModify()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) is quite different to the shell syntax. The "query" and "update" parts are separate arguments there rather than the document form as used by the shell,

Answer (score 1):

To update an individual element in the array "features" you can use the positional operator, $. Your query would look something like this...

```
db.rescuemodels.findAndModify({
    query: {
        "features": {
            $elemMatch: {
                "properties.title": "W"
            }
        }
    },
    update: {
        $set: {
            "features.$.properties.title": "XXX"
        }
    }
})
```